# 'history', no-restricted-globals, and window.history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I was running into an issue with React where if I tried to use 'history', my code wouldn't run telling me it's an 'unexpected use of `history` no-restricted-global'.

I turned to StackOverflow in order to get help and surprisingly, I was able to find an answer to the issue that I was dealing with.

The fix that another use suggested worked great, but now I'm confused as to why it worked in the first place.

Using redux, I called a method via mapDispatchToProps. I needed to throw the 'history' in as one of the variables passed in so that I can redirect the user back to the previous page that they were on.

Originally, I tried using just 'history' by itself as a variable but I would get a 'no-restricted-global' error when I tried to compile so I turned to StackOverflow. This is when they suggested I try using 'window.history'. I was skeptical at first because I didn't think something that simple would fix my issue but lo and behold, it compiled successfully.

```
props.addExperience(data, history);
```

vs.

```
props.addExperience(data, window.history);
```

the window.history works. Can someone please explain why the window.history works but history by itself doesn't work?

what exactly is 'history'? what does 'window' do that fixes the issue?

edit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991656/no-restricted-globals) is the original StackOverflow post that I found. While Chasen Bettinger was able to fix the issue, he never really explained *why* the window. would fix the issue. If someone here can do that, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem that the linting rule you're running into is attempting to solve is that implicitly referring to properties on the global object is an [easy source of bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-avoid-accidentally-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-objec). For example:

```js
var status = false;
if (status) {
  console.log('status is actually truthy!');
}
```

Here, `status` on the top level actually refers to `window.status`, which must always be a string; assigning `false` to it results in `false` turning into `'false'`.

If `status` was a restricted global with that rule, you would only be able to use `status` on the top level if you explicitly referred to `window.status`. That way, it's clear that you're *deliberately* referring to the global property, and that it's not an accident.

The same sort of thing is going on when you refer to `window.history` instead of `history`. For example, what if, earlier in the code, you defined a variable

```
var history;
```

and then used

```
props.addExperience(data, history);
```

The linter doesn't know for sure whether you're trying to refer to the property on the global object, or if you made a typo. So, the rule is there to get you to *explicitly specify* that the property is on the `window` (or to correct the variable name).

As for what `window.history` actually is, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history):

> The `Window.history` read-only property returns a reference to the History object, which provides an interface for manipulating the browser session history (pages visited in the tab or frame that the current page is loaded in).

eg

```
history.back();     // equivalent to clicking back button
history.go(-1);     // equivalent to history.back();
window.history.go(0); // refresh the current page
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html"); // add an item to the history state
```